# Server Side processing with Datatables v1.10.0

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datatable

Hi I'm having some issues getting the server side processing functionality of data tables to work with SQL Server.

I've got a test page that should display two columns from a database table(for now).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.0/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th align="center">PK</th>
            <th align="center">Network</th>               
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
            <th align="center">PK</th>
            <th align="center">Network</th>               
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.0/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "ajax": "PHP/testGetArchive.php"
    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

I'm using the example code found on the website Here for the server side functions:

http://next.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

This is my version of the php page being called:

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'tblViews';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'PK';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'PK', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Network',  'dt' => 1 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '******',
    'pass' => '******',
    'db'   => '******db',
    'host' => '******\SQLEXPRESS'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

This then calls the second example PHP found here:

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Here is my Copy of it. The only Modification I performed was to remove the block of code that is required for the examples.

```
<?php

/*
 * Helper functions for building a DataTables server-side processing SQL query
 *
 * The static functions in this class are just helper functions to help build
 * the SQL used in the DataTables demo server-side processing scripts. These
 * functions obviously do not represent all that can be done with server-side
 * processing, they are intentionally simple to show how it works. More complex
 * server-side processing operations will likely require a custom script.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

class SSP {
    /**
     * Create the data output array for the DataTables rows
     *
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $data    Data from the SQL get
     *  @return array          Formatted data in a row based format
     */
    static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $row = array();

            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
                $column = $columns[$j];

                // Is there a formatter?
                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
                }
                else {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
                }
            }

            $out[] = $row;
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Paging
     *
     * Construct the LIMIT clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL limit clause
     */
    static function limit ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $limit = '';

        if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
            $limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
        }

        return $limit;
    }


    /**
     * Ordering
     *
     * Construct the ORDER BY clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL order by clause
     */
    static function order ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $order = '';

        if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
            $orderBy = array();
            $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];

                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                        'ASC' :
                        'DESC';

                    $orderBy[] = '`'.$column['db'].'` '.$dir;
                }
            }

            $order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
        }

        return $order;
    }


    /**
     * Searching / Filtering
     *
     * Construct the WHERE clause for server-side processing SQL query.
     *
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here performance on large
     * databases would be very poor
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $bindings Array of values for PDO bindings, used in the
     *    sql_exec() function
     *  @return string SQL where clause
     */
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            $str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
             $str != '' ) {
                $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $columnSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }

        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';

        if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
            $where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
        }

        if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
            $where = $where === '' ?
                implode(' AND ', $columnSearch) :
                $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $columnSearch);
        }

        if ( $where !== '' ) {
            $where = 'WHERE '.$where;
        }

        return $where;
    }


    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others. The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $sql_details SQL connection details - see sql_connect()
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function simple ( $request, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = SSP::sql_connect( $sql_details );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = SSP::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = SSP::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = SSP::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = SSP::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".implode("`, `", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];


        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => intval( $request['draw'] ),
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => SSP::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }


    /**
     * Connect to the database
     *
     * @param  array $sql_details SQL server connection details array, with the
     *   properties:
     *     * host - host name
     *     * db   - database name
     *     * user - user name
     *     * pass - user password
     * @return resource Database connection handle
     */
    static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
    {
        try {
            $db = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
                $sql_details['user'],
                $sql_details['pass'],
                array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            SSP::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        return $db;
    }


    /**
     * Execute an SQL query on the database
     *
     * @param  resource $db  Database handler
     * @param  array    $bindings Array of PDO binding values from bind() to be
     *   used for safely escaping strings. Note that this can be given as the
     *   SQL query string if no bindings are required.
     * @param  string   $sql SQL query to execute.
     * @return array         Result from the query (all rows)
     */
    static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
    {
        // Argument shifting
        if ( $sql === null ) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
        //echo $sql;

        // Bind parameters
        if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $binding = $bindings[$i];
                $stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
            }
        }

        // Execute
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            SSP::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
        }

        // Return all
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Internal methods
     */

    /**
     * Throw a fatal error.
     *
     * This writes out an error message in a JSON string which DataTables will
     * see and show to the user in the browser.
     *
     * @param  string $msg Message to send to the client
     */
    static function fatal ( $msg )
    {
        echo json_encode( array( 
            "error" => $msg
        ) );

        exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDO binding key which can be used for escaping variables safely
     * when executing a query with sql_exec()
     *
     * @param  array &$a    Array of bindings
     * @param  *      $val  Value to bind
     * @param  int    $type PDO field type
     * @return string       Bound key to be used in the SQL where this parameter
     *   would be used.
     */
    static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
    {
        $key = ':binding_'.count( $a );

        $a[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'val' => $val,
            'type' => $type
        );

        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Pull a particular property from each assoc. array in a numeric array, 
     * returning and array of the property values from each item.
     *
     *  @param  array  $a    Array to get data from
     *  @param  string $prop Property to read
     *  @return array        Array of property values
     */
    static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $out[] = $a[$i][$prop];
        }

        return $out;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error saying that the code cannot find the driver though I've got the sqlserv and pdo_sqlsrv Drivers installed din my php environment. Is there something wrong on the code that's causing this error? Are my drivers incorrect? Any help with this would be appreciated. I've got upwards of 65,000 rows of data to process and to send that all to the client in one go will be impossible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me a while But I've found out where I was going wrong and I now have DataTables working with SQL Server through server side scripts. I'm posting this solution in the hope that it will help anyone else like me who was having issues. I've broken my answer into parts.

**The PHP Environment**

The SQLSRV drivers for php can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). Download the SQLSRV30.EXE installer package. You may find that when you try and run this executable that you get the error "This is not a valid win32 application" If this is the case unzip the executable with something like 7-zip. The resulting file will have the files you require inside.

When you've unzipped the package you need to select the right driver. Most windows installations use the non thread safe drivers these are:

**php version 5.3:**

php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

**php version 5.4:**

php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll

php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll

Copy the appropriate files to the ext folder within your php directory. Now modify your php.ini file to have a reference to these files. Do this by adding an entry under the dynamic extensions section. The result would be something like this:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
```

And then add a section for the driver under the Module section settings like this:

```
[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubSystems=-1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity=-1
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors=0
```

The documentation for these settings can be found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx).

Once you have added these drivers and added a reference to them in the php.ini file you must also ensure that the Microsoft SQL Server Client Profile 2012 is also installed.

[These Links have been taken from the PHP.net website:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php)

[Microsoft SQL Server Client Profile 2012 x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239647)
[Microsoft SQL Server Client profile 2012 x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648)

Once you have performed these steps restart your web server. The driver should now be installed and ready to use. You can check this using your info.php page.

**The Server Side Script:**

Now that the web-server has been configured to use the SQL SRV driver we can now use it to query a SQL Server database. I've used the server side script available [here](http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mssql_odbc). Here are some issues I found with it:

```
<?php
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "";

    /*
    * Columns
    * If you don't want all of the columns displayed you need to hardcode $aColumns array with your elements.
    * If not this will grab all the columns associated with $sTable
    */
    $aColumns = array();


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * ODBC connection
     */
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $gaSql['user'], "PWD" => $gaSql['password'], "Database"=>$gaSql['db'],"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true);
    $gaSql['link'] = sqlsrv_connect( $gaSql['server'], $connectionInfo);
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );


    /* Ordering */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) ) {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" ) {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".addslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    /* Filtering */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )  {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            } else {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }

    /* Paging */
    $top = (isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']))?((int)$_GET['iDisplayStart']):0 ;
    $limit = (isset($_GET['iDisplayLength']))?((int)$_GET['iDisplayLength'] ):10;
    $sQuery = "SELECT TOP $limit ".implode(",",$aColumns)."
        FROM $sTable
        $sWhere ".(($sWhere=="")?" WHERE ":" AND ")." $sIndexColumn NOT IN
        (
            SELECT $sIndexColumn FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP $top ".implode(",",$aColumns)."
                FROM $sTable
                $sWhere
                $sOrder
            )
            as [virtTable]
        )
        $sOrder";

    $rResult = sqlsrv_query($gaSql['link'],$sQuery) or die("$sQuery: " . sqlsrv_errors());

    $sQueryCnt = "SELECT * FROM $sTable $sWhere";
    $rResultCnt = sqlsrv_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQueryCnt ,$params, $options) or die (" $sQueryCnt: " . sqlsrv_errors());
    $iFilteredTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $rResultCnt );

    $sQuery = " SELECT * FROM $sTable ";
    $rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ,$params, $options) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
    $iTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $rResultTotal );

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult ) ) {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' ) {
                $v = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
                $v = mb_check_encoding($v, 'UTF-8') ? $v : utf8_encode($v);
                $row[]=$v;
            }
        }
        If (!empty($row)) { $output['aaData'][] = $row; }
    }   
    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

**The Indexed Column**

When you specify an indexed column to use for searches make sure that it is included in the column array! if you leave it out when specifying which columns to use the paging will not work. The paging of datatables with this code works be performing a select query of all primary keys when not in the TOP X results from another query.

**The Connection Parameters**

Ensure that the connection parameters are  complete and correct. These are necessary to allow the script to connect to the database. If there aren't any parameters or the parameters are not correct to a SQL server login then the script will never be able to connect to the database.

**The Column Array**

I found that using this code without specified columns returned incorrect or NULL data. The best way to stop this was to fill the array with the column names I wanted to select each enclosed by quotes and separated by commas. It also stands to reason as why send anything but the required data back to the client?

**The Client Side**

**HTML**

DataTables requires a well formed html table to operate. This means having a table with full  tags. If all of the tags are not there for the data being returned then DataTables will return an error. If you have columns that you want to return but not show then you can use the [ColVis exntension](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) and set a default column view setting in the java script.

**Datatable uses its own CCS file so make sure you include it!**

**The java script**

**DataTables uses Jquery and its own Javascrpt file so make sure you include references to them within your script tags!**

```
//Datatables Basic server side initilization
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Datatable
    var table = $('#tableID').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "serverSideScript.php"
    });    
});
```

These are the basic functions required for this server side script to work. It will get the top 10 rows on initial draw using the database parameters you specify in the php page. From here you can add the extensions you want such as [ColVis](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) and [TableTools](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/). Full Documentation for these Extensions and other initialization options for data tables can be found [here](http://www.datatables.net/).

I Hope this answer helps anyone else who is having the same issues that I had.

Comment: Thanks mate! Was trying to find something like this.

Comment: Its kind of dated now, not the way I would do it but it works so some level. I've still not found a perfect solution for it but when I eventually do I'll update with another answer.